# How to Remove Body Element on Elementor Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

As you can see from the picture, I have the site name that appears on top of my website and I want to remove it. The problem is that I can't figure out how to remove it. The variable is a text variable at the start of the body section. I went to edit the theme and I can't find that text, I tried to remove all the plugins I installed and still nothing, I can't really understand where to look to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the **header or the footer files** of your active template ?

Also the overall configuration on the customizer side ?

If you already did all this, then let check the overall wordpress installation options over `https://mytld.tld/wp-admin/options.php`.

If you are still not successful then go to your database to consistently remove it!

Hopefully, this will help you by!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is really strange. There is nothing in the source code as you can see with i.e. "view-source:https://damamma.net", so it's there because of a script.
Deactivate the Plugin PixelYourSite and check again.

I don't think it is caused by Wordpress itself, Elementor or the Theme.